# Problem Getting/Reading Webservice Response in Axis 1.4

Tags: web-services, exception, axis

I am using Axis 1.4 to to create a webservice client because the service uses RPC encoding.  I've autogenerated the client code using wsdl2java based on a provided wsdl file.  I can't get the wsdl from the service itself using ?wsdl appended to the service URL because it does't accept GET requests.

When I try to access the service via the client, it first logs this exception:

```
DEBUG org.apache.axis.ConfigurationException  - Exception: 
org.apache.axis.ConfigurationException: No service named GetSettings is available
```

I've read in other posts that this isn't something to worry about.  However, if I could get rid of it it would be nice.  My client class looks like this (try/catches removed):

```
private String endpoint = "http://<IP>/ToolsServlet/";

private ToolsServiceLocator locator;
private ToolsPort service;

public ToolsClient()
{
    locator = new ToolsServiceLocator();        
    URL url = new URL(endpoint);
    service = locator.getToolsService(url);            
}

public SwitchSettingsType getProvisionedSettings(String value)
{
    SettingsType settings = service.getSettings(value);

    return settings;
}
```

My real problem lies in that I get exceptions trying to parse the response.  For example:

```
INFO: 13:59:17,361 [http-thread-pool-8080-(2)] ERROR org.apache.axis.client.Call  - Exception:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid boolean
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.SimpleDeserializer.onEndElement(SimpleDeserializer.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializerImpl.endElement(DeserializerImpl.java:502)
...

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid boolean
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.SimpleDeserializer.makeBasicValue(SimpleDeserializer.java:270)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.SimpleDeserializer.makeValue(SimpleDeserializer.java:209)
    at org.apache.axis.encoding.ser.SimpleDeserializer.onEndElement(SimpleDeserializer.java:172)
    ... 40 more
```

With debug level loggin on, this exception is preceded by the logging of the request and these lines:

```
DEBUG org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender  - POST /ToolsServlet/ HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Accept: application/soap+xml, application/dime, multipart/related, text/*
User-Agent: Axis/1.4
Host: <IP>
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
SOAPAction: "GetSettings"
Content-Length: 479
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><ns1:GetSettings soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="urn:tools"><value xsi:type="xsd:string">value</value></ns1:GetSettings></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
DEBUG org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender  - HTTP/1.1 200 OK
DEBUG org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender  - Date Mon, 08 Nov 2010 20:59:12 GMT
DEBUG org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender  - Server Apache/2.0.53 (Unix) DAV/2
DEBUG org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender  - Connection close
DEBUG org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender  - Content-Type text/xml
DEBUG org.apache.axis.SOAPPart  - Enter: SOAPPart ctor(FORM_INPUTSTREAM)
DEBUG org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle  - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(setMsgForm)
DEBUG org.apache.axis.SOAPPart  - Setting current message form to: FORM_INPUTSTREAM (currentMessage is now org.apache.axis.transport.http.SocketInputStream)
DEBUG org.apache.axis.SOAPPart  - Exit: SOAPPart ctor()
DEBUG org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle  - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(no00)
DEBUG org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender  - 
no Content-Length
DEBUG org.apache.axis.i18n.ProjectResourceBundle  - org.apache.axis.i18n.resource::handleGetObject(xmlRecd00)
DEBUG org.apache.axis.transport.http.HTTPSender  - 
XML received:
```

It appears to me I am not receiving a proper response back.  I tested direct post against the webservice using Firefox and the Poster addon.  I used the SOAP message/request generated by my client and I do get back a valid response.

Am I reading the logs correctly in that Axis thinks that there is an empty response?  If so, does anybody have any suggestions as to why Axis is not getting a response or not reading it correctly?  I can't see anything else in the logs that provides any clue.

**Start Update One**

It appears that I am getting back a response even though it's not logged in that one place, but further log statements show attempts to parse the response via DeserializationContext.  Axis is throwing a NumberFormatException because it's expecting `'0', 'f' or 'F'` for false and `'1', 't' or 'T'` for true.  It doesn't like 'true' or 'false' which is really warped since the wsdl defines the elements as xsd:boolean and the allowed values are `'true'` and `'false'`.

Other than updating the source code to process 'true' and 'false' correctly, are there any suggestions to making Axis work?

TIA

**End Update One**

**Start Update Two**

Fresh eyes the next day help. The Axis code handles `true` and `false` because it's getting the first char of the string.  The issue is that I'm receiving bad data.

**End Update Two**

Comment: The way you have edited your question makes it impossible to understand. Please edit it again, and put the original question first, followed by the updates, in order.